# Ember server not working.

Tags: ember.js

I have below on Windows 10:
o   Ember-cli: 2.4.3
o   Node: 6.11.0
o   Npm – 5.0.3

I am executing command ember server from admin command prompt and get below error:
Livereload failed on http://localhost:49152.  It is either in use or you do not have permission.

Then I tried ember serve --port 8080 --live-reload-port 35735 and it is hanging up. Please tell me how to correct this.

Comment: Have you tried `--live-reload-port 0`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but it could be you already have another process running on that port.  Given the error, it sounds unlikely, though.  Run the following command:

`netstat -a -o -n`

Check that command's output for any processes running on the ports in question. 
 You can try killing any processes running on those ports using (obviously, some caution is in order here):

`taskkill /F /PID [pid from previous command here]`

And in case you're curious, I found this on a Java developer's blog: http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2015/04/16/windows-kill-process-by-port-number

Comment: Reinstalled all the pieces after full clean up and it went away. Thank you for your help.